# Android: Receive packets from only one ip address

Tags: android

how to make my android tablet receive data packets from only one ip address through wifi and not to allow it to receive from other ip address.

here is the code

**- for scan and then registering**

```
String connectivity_context = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
            final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(connectivity_context);  
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                        wifi.startScan();
                    }


IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ScanWiFiActivity a = ScanWiFiActivity.instance();
        WifiManager w = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<ScanResult> l = w.getScanResults();
        a.Clear();
        for (ScanResult r : l) {
                              //do what i want with the required result
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, i);
```

in the for block i will do the required things.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i want that if i am receiving packets from a specific ip address then my tablet should not be allowed to pair with other till i want or you can say till my application is running.

Comment: You can write an ACL in the router itself so that it routes to the IP of your phone.. But then, since your phone will be connected by wi-fi, achieving this can be difficult.. But as @Jaguar says, what have you tried?

Comment: I havent tried anything now. I want to know is it possible or not? And if yes, then the way?

Comment: @prabhanshu first google the things and if you find any difficulty while programming and stuck somewhere, we will definitely help you.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @commonsware it has to be solved by programming

Comment: @jaguar is the code write.. :)

Answer (score 0):

> it has to be solved by programming

This is not possible, except by modifying the firmware.

Depending on your definition of "programming", you could probably modify iptables on a rooted device from an app running as superuser, but the crux of that (configuring iptables) is not a programming question and so is off-topic for StackOverflow.